# What is the term for the object to be identified in a pattern recognition problem?

Tags: terminology, pattern-recognition

What is the term for the object to be identified in a pattern recognition problem?

So, for example, if one were matching a glyph expected to be an alphabetic letter to a set of templates, what is the glyph called? The sample?